# Perl autosplit with non-file arguments

Tags: perl, split, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to create a perl script that autosplits the STDIN, and then does something to column X. But I want the column to be passed by argument to the script. However, apparently, when I invoke perl with the autosplit flag, it switches to a mode where it tries to implicitly open the "files" defined in the command line arguments, even though my arguments aren't files.

Example:

```
my $column = shift;

while(<STDIN>) {
      print "F $column: $F[$column]!\n";
}
```

Then I try to run it with argument `2` to print the 2nd column:

```
$ echo -e "1 22\n2 33\n3 55" | perl -a myscript.pl 2
```

When I turn on warnings and such, I get this error message:

```
Can't open 2: No such file or directory (#1)
    (S inplace) The implicit opening of a file through use of the <>
    filehandle, either implicitly under the -n or -p command-line
    switches, or explicitly, failed for the indicated reason.  Usually
    this is because you don't have read permission for a file which
    you named on the command line.

    (F) You tried to call perl with the -e switch, but /dev/null (or
    your operating system's equivalent) could not be opened.
```

If I omit the `-a`, I don't get any errors and all is good, but then I need to manually split my lines. Is there any other flag I can use to make autosplit not do that? Or alternatively, can I start autosplit inside the script, so that it won't try to implicitly open the arguments as files? I can manually split my input, I just wanted to know what other alternatives I have.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much of a "mode" here. `-n` adds

```
while (readline) {
    ...
}
```

around your code; `-a` adds a split statement:

```
while (readline) {
    our @F = split;
    ...
}
```

`readline` (without argument) reads from the filenames specified in `@ARGV` (or `STDIN` if `@ARGV` is empty).

`-a` implicitly enables `-n` because otherwise there is nothing for it to do; there is no "autosplit mode", it simply adds code around your program.

Your best bet is to split manually:

```
while (<STDIN>) {
    my @F = split;
    print "F $column: $F[$column]!\n";
}
```

It's fairly short and it makes it obvious what's going on.

I don't like using the command line shortcut switches (e.g. `-a`, `-p`, etc.) in script files. In a file you have enough space to write multiple lines, properly formatted / indented. It's better to be explicit.

---

That said, you can technically do this:

```
#!perl -na
our $column;
BEGIN { $column = shift; }
print "F $column: $F[$column]!\n";
```

This is equivalent to:

```
while (readline) {
    our @F = split;
    our $column;
    BEGIN { $column = shift; }
    print "F $column: $F[$column]!\n";
}
```

The `BEGIN` block only runs once, at compile time. Provided the script is only called with one argument, this will remove it from `@ARGV` before the `readline` loop starts, which will make it read from `STDIN`.

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea. I had to remove my "while", the fact that `-a` enables `-n` was unexpected but I'm ok with it.

Comment: Why are you lying about what Perl adds?

Comment: @ikegami Which part is a lie?

Comment: The reversion. .

Comment: @ikegami Can you be more specific?

Comment: Before that, it could have been a mistake, but now you intentionally changed it from the corrected version.

Comment: Or are you asking what's the [truth](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/1654584e05038fee2cc4307f292f18e445d0e50f:/toke.c#l5300)? You've just reverted it.

Comment: @ikegami The only functional change you made was to add a `LINE:` label, which is unused, so I omitted it from the explanation. That doesn't make my answer wrong.

Comment: Your claim that it's what Perl adds is what's wrong. Similar, sure, but that's not what you claimed.

Comment: It's not what Perl adds. You said that's what Perl adds.

Comment: @ikegami Wait, are you complaining that I used a different spelling of the same operators? `<>` vs. `readline`, etc?

Comment: There that, but there's also the functional changes.

Comment: @ikegami What functional changes?

Comment: Label presence and line numbering.

Comment: @ikegami The label is not functional in this program, and I didn't say the code in my answer is all that `-n` adds. It's just the relevant parts. I don't know what you mean by line numbering; your edit didn't add/remove any lines.

Comment: By your logic. I never claimed my edit was complete, so it was perfectly fine even though I missed something. Ridiculous, eh?

Comment: @ikegami Then, by your logic, you were also lying about what Perl adds. But seriously, I still don't know what you mean by line numbering.

Comment: No, I was mistaken, not lying. When the mistake was identified, I owned up to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164377/discussion-between-melpomene-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 0):

`-n`, `-p`, `-l`, `-a` and `-F` don't change the state of the Perl interpreter. They literally alter the source code.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -a -ne'f()'
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    our @F = split(' ', $_, 0);
    f();
}
-e syntax OK
```

As you can see, there's really no such thing as autosplit. It's just a normal `split` injected into the source code, and it makes no sense to ask Perl to insert a `split` instead of just inserting a `split`. So, simply add the following to your loop:

```
my @F = split;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. :) But this seems more like a comment than an answer... I don't understand how that explains the behaviour I'm seeing (does that mean `readline` is the one trying to open the argument as a file?) or how that gives me an alternative that will help me not manually split inside my code. :thinking: